# Bi-directional horizontal scrolling html/css

Tags: html, css

I want to implement a layout where by default a user can scroll a child element both left to right and right to left within its container.
RIght now if a make the child wider than its container, and set the overflow to `overflow: scroll` I can scroll the child div to the left.

[image]

But I want the initial state to be like this:
[image]

So that a user can initially scroll in either direction.

This is for an html email so there can be NO javascript. This is also targeting mobile touch devices.

The code for this image is this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />

<style>
  .container{
  width: 400px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: initial;
}

.child{
  position: relative;
  border: 2px dotted green;
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
}
</style>


<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://illuminatecosmeticmedicine.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Blank-Profile.jpg" width="200px" style="margin-left: 300px" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

But if I change the overflow of the container to `scroll` or `auto` It still only lets me scroll the right part of the child into view, not the left part. How can I achieve this?